# Why doesn't docker-compose 'down' take an optional [SERVICE...] argument?

Tags: docker-compose

`docker-compose down` does not have a `[SERVICE...]` argument.
Per `docker-compose down --help`:

```
Usage: down [options]
```

I would like to be able to bring just one of my many containers down.  I know that I can down a single container using `docker down` instead of `docker-compose down`, but I'm wondering why doesn't the `docker-compose down` command take an optional `[SERVICE...]` argument?

All of the following docker-compose commands **do** take an optional `[SERVICE...]` argument:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose create
docker-compose kill
docker-compose logs
docker-compose pause
docker-compose restart
docker-compose rm
docker-compose start
docker-compose stop
docker-compose unpause
docker-compose up
```

My `docker-compose --version` is `1.9.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `docker down`. The corresponding docker command is closer to: `docker stop; docker rm`

From [docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/):

> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up.
>
> By default, the only things removed are:
>
> - Containers for services defined in the Compose file
> - Networks defined in the networks section of the Compose file
> - The default network, if one is used

If `docker-compose down` removes networks also, then by removing one container, it should also automatically disconnect the other containers from these networks, which might be undesirable or confusing.

It could change so that by default `docker down` does not remove the networks, but that change might cause backwards-compatibility issues with the command.

This is just an assumption.

Comment: I see.  But wouldn't it make sense to leave the networking up if you just `docker-compose down my-service`?  Are you saying it would be inconsistent behavior with `docker-compose down` (i.e., remove networking for `docker-compose down`, but not for `docker-compose down my-service`)?

Answer (score 12):

The following command is the equivalent of `docker down` for a single service:

```
docker-compose rm -s -v my_service
```

> Usage: rm [options] [SERVICE...]
>
> Options:
> -s, --stop Stop the containers, if required, before removing 
> -v Remove any anonymous volumes attached to containers